# getRGB(x,y) in Java awt returns for each pixel same value

Tags: java, image-processing, awt, rgb

I tried to walk through an image and take each RGB color value from all pixels and process them. But I get for all pixels the same RGB value. So obviously that is wrong.

I used the ***getRGB(x,y)*** method of an ***bufferedimage*** object in Java awt.
Know anyone what's the problem here?

Edit:

I got the problem, there were some mistakes by converting the image to an buffered image. I didn't draw the image in the in the buffered image.
The Following code working now as intended.

```
    public void printImgDetails(Image img) {

    // get the sizes of the image
    long heigth = img.getHeight(null);
    long width = img.getWidth(null);

    // hashSet to hold all brightness values
    HashSet<Float> set = new HashSet<Float>(0);

    BufferedImage bimage = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
    int rgb;
    float[] hsv = new float[3];

    // Draw the image on to the buffered image
    Graphics2D bGr = bimage.createGraphics();
    bGr.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    bGr.dispose();

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < heigth; j++) {
            Color c = new Color(bimage.getRGB(j, i));

            int r = c.getRed();
            int g = c.getGreen();
            int b = c.getBlue();

            Color.RGBtoHSB(r, g, b, hsv);
            System.out.println("r: " + r + " g: " + g + " b: " + b);
            set.add(hsv[2]);
        }
    }

    // calculate the average brightness
    double sum = 0;
    for (float x : set) {
        sum += x;
    }
    double avg = sum / set.size();

    // print the results
    System.out.println("avg --> " + avg);

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A guess: the problem is somewhere in your code ... right there, see it? Seriously: how are we supposed to help if you don't even show any code? And did you step through your code with a debugger yet?

Comment: please read [ask]

Comment: first thanks for your answer, here is the code and of corse Id step trough with a debugger. But now it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get the same values for every pixel there are several possible reasons.

a) your image has the same values in every pixel

b) you do not change x and y between your calls to `getRGB`

c) you read something else but the return value of `getRGB`

Answer (score 1):

As I wirte in the edit, there was an problem by converting between image and bufferedimage. I forgot to draw image into the bufferediamge. Thats it.

Comment: consider deleting your question. I doubt it's of any use to anyone

Comment: This question helped me solve a problem I was having.